# CodeIgniter 3 get data from 3 tables and save as xml

Tags: xml, codeigniter

I write model with below code:

```
 public function generate_google(){
        $this->db->select('*'); // <-- There is never any reason to write this line!
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->join('product_details', 'products.id = product_details.product_id');
$this->db->join('images', 'products.id = images.product_id');

$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    
$xml = '<root>';
foreach($query as $row){
  $xml .= '<item>
             <sku>'.$row['sku'].'</sku>
             <price>'.$row['price'].'</price>
             <stock>'.$row['stock'].'</stock>
             <title>'.$row['title'].'</title>
           </item>';
}
$xml .= '</root>';
$this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');
$this->output->set_output($xml);
        
        
    }
```

1. How to add option to save xml file without display output in browser?
2. and the last how to add rule `WHERE products.stock >= 1` ?

@update please see below is my update code for model controller and view

sitemap_model.php

```
public function get_all_products() {
        $this->db->select('products.*, product_details.*, images.*')
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->join('product_details','product_details.product_id = products.id');
        $this->db->join('images','images.product_id = products.id');
        $this->db->where('products.stock >=' 1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

sitemap_controller.php

```
public function generate_google_post()
{
$this->load->model('sitemap_model');

$xml   = '<root>';
$query = $sitemap_model->get_all_products();

foreach ($query as $row) {
    $xml .= '<item>
        <sku>'.$row['sku'].'</sku>
        <price>'.$row['price'].'</price>
        <stock>'.$row['stock'].'</stock>
        <title>'.$row['title'].'</title>
    </item>';
}

$xml .= '</root>';

header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');

echo $xml;
}
```

view.php

```
<?php echo form_open('sitemap_controller/generate_google_post'); ?>
            
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="process" value="generate" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo trans('download_sitemap'); ?></button>
                
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-footer -->

        <?php echo form_close(); ?><!-- form end -->
```

Im not sure from this error come but when I click generate I get this error which I paste in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be something like this:

```
$this->db->select('products.*, product_details.*, images.*');
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->join('product_details', 'product_details.product_id = products.id');
$this->db->join('images', 'images.product_id = products.id');
$this->db->where('products.stock >=', 1);

$query      = $this->db->get();
$mysql_data = $query->result_array();
```

And, to download the XML, instead those lines:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('text/xml');
$this->output->set_output($xml);
```

Try this:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');

echo $xml;
```

By the way, I suggest you to include the database queries into a model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Products_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_all_products() {
        $this->db->select('products.*, product_details.*, images.*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->join('product_details', 'product_details.product_id = products.id');
        $this->db->join('images', 'images.product_id = products.id');
        $this->db->where('products.stock >=', 1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

And then call it from the controller:

```
public function generate_google() {
    $this->load->model('products_model');

    $query = $products_model->get_all_products();
    $xml   = '<root>';

    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $xml .= '<item>
            <sku>'.$row['sku'].'</sku>
            <price>'.$row['price'].'</price>
            <stock>'.$row['stock'].'</stock>
            <title>'.$row['title'].'</title>
        </item>';
    }

    $xml .= '</root>';

    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');

    echo $xml;
}
```

Comment: I set as your said in second solution. But currently I get: Message: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

Filename: public_html/application/models/Sitemap_model.php

Line Number: 292 $this->db->join('product_details','product_details.product_id = products.id');

Comment: Show us your model code to check it.

Comment: can you please check my update

Comment: In your controller, you're calling a 'products_model' but in the error included in your comment, occurs on a file called 'Sitemap_model.php'. The name you provide to the model's file should be the same that the model you call on $this->load->model('products_model');

Comment: sorry I past you wrong data without changes. Please refresh page, i changed it immediately after few sec in my update but I    getting this error with correct path to  my model etc

Comment: Now is Message: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) /Sitemap_model.php

Line Number: 291  $this->db->from('products');

Comment: These types of errors often occur because of a missing semicolon on a previous line. If not, add the code of your model to be able to check it.